# SQL server - Login failed for user ''.

Tags: sql-server, iis

Not sure if this should go on this forum or on IIS forum...

I have an IIS 7.5 web site on a 2008 R2 box with the application pool configured to run under a local user called ProcessIIS.

This web site then connects to a sql database on the same box under windows authentication.

However every time it tries to make the connection it fails at the sql side with an error -Login failed for user ''. Reason: An attempt to login using SQL authentication failed. Server is configured for Windows authentication only. [CLIENT: ]

If I change the application pool identity to IUSR then the correct name is picked up ( although the login fails this time due to rights).

I have already configured a test box the exact same way and no issue was found - any ideas ?

Comment: `Server is configured for Windows authentication only`

Comment: I know server is configured for windows authentication only - that's why I'm using integrated security & running IIS under a local windows user identity

Comment: It looks like the error is saying that you're connecting to it using SQL Server auth.  Check your connection string.

Comment: I think the error is a bit of a red herring - the connection string is correct - this is proven by the fact that when I change the app pool identity the correct windows user is passed

Comment: Does that user exist in SQL Server?

Comment: user existed - even if it didn't then I would expect to see a login failure with the user name instead of just ""

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok - solved this - not exactly sure what was wrong. But after deleting the user completely, removing the server from the domain. Readding the server back to the domain, recreating the user and finally adding the user back into SQL & IIS all works correctly ???